# Hide event of bootstrap modal not being fired

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have my modal defined in cshtml as shown below.  When I click on the cross mark or on the close button, I want to perform some action but the hide event is not getting fired.

```
<div id="addD" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="addPatientLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" 
                data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="addLabel">Create</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="validateTips"></p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="TemplateLabel">
                    Name:
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input placeholder="name" type="text" name="Name" 
                           data-bind="value: NewP.Name" id="SignUpName" 
                           class="SignUp text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SaveD()">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#AddD').on("hidden", function () {
        debugger;
        alert("blah");
    });
}
```

Comment: check your ID in html vs. the ID in javascript. mismatch?

Comment: why don't you use [live bootstrap sample](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) ?

Comment: Yes, the ID was a mismatch. It works now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you give the id of '#addD' to the modal and then expect the element $('#AddD') to trigger the event.

Comment: This does not resolve the entire issue as the [event name is still wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/zYrP2/2/).

Comment: The event name is not wrong as the user seems to be using bootstrap 2 at least according to modal window markup http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Although if user is using bootstrap3 then the event should be 'hidden.bs.modal' indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

#### For Bootstrap 3.0:

[According to the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage), the available event types are as follows:

> - `show.bs.modal`
> - `shown.bs.modal`
> - `hide.bs.modal`
> - `hidden.bs.modal`
> - `loaded.bs.modal`

You have to use the properly namespaced event like this:

```
$('#addD').on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    alert("blah");
});
```

Also, as was already pointed out, the ID selector was different between your HTML and Javascript

### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/zYrP2/)